# How to add dependency to CMakeLists.txt

Tags: make, cmake

I am working on an already build shared library.

When I run `cmake -C $ILCSOFT/ILCSoft.cmake` the output says at somepoint:

```
-- Check for FastJet (3.1.2)
-- Check for FastJet_LIBRARIES: fastjet
-- Check for FastJet_FASTJET_LIBRARY: /cvmfs/foo...bar/FastJet/3.1.2/lib/libfastjet.so -- ok
...
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH =
-- /cvmfs/foo...bar/v01-17-09/FastJet/3.1.2;
```

But when I run `make install` my cc file fails at `#include "fastjet/ClusterSequence.hh"`.

Which means I am not setting up my cmake properly. Right now I am trying to add my fastjet dependency by doing in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( FastJet )
LINK_LIBRARIES( FastJet_LIBRARY )
```

No errors are thrown, but I cannot import the stuff I want.

I don't think I understand cmake, make and cpp imports for that matter. Could anyone help me?

How do I import a this large library into my cmake?

Answer (score 1):

If it’s chocking at the include stage it’s finding the include directories that’s the problem, not the actual location of a compiles library. From [the cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html), so try adding where that libraries headers are.

> include_directories
>
> Add include directories to the build.
>
> include_directories([AFTER|BEFORE] [SYSTEM] dir1 [dir2 ...])
>
> Add the given directories to those the compiler uses to search for include
> files. Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the current
> source directory.